# Large deviation for a sequence of counts

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We are working on a problem related to the configuration model and need a bound on the vertex degrees.

Let $d_1,d_2,\cdots$ be an iid sequence with $d_i \sim Poisson(\mu)$ and $p_k = e^{-\mu} \mu^k/k!$. After revealing the first $n$, define the proportion of $d_i$ equal to $k$ as $$X_k^{(n)} = \frac{ \#\{ i\leq n \colon d_i = k \}}{n}.$$

Given $\epsilon>0$ let $A_k^{(n)} = \{ (1-\epsilon)p_k < X_k^{(n)} < (1+\epsilon)p_k \}$ be the event that the proportions are within $1\pm \epsilon$ of the mean. Is it true that for any $\epsilon >0$ it holds that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigcup _{k \geq 0 } A_{k}^{(n)} = 1.$$

This is easy to see for $\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigcup_{0 \leq k \leq m} A_k^{(n)} \to 1$ for fixed $m$ via a Chernoff and then union bound. However, the infinite case seems trickier. Perhaps it is a simple Borel-Cantelli argument that we are missing.